# String literal in Swift - new line character \n not recognized

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to declare a string that contains my public RSA key. In Objective-C I did it like this:

```
NSString *pubKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
  "MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu\n"
  "ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A\n"
  "+xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw\n"
  "mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN\n"
  "QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P\n"
  "+0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB\n"
  "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

When I display this string in the debugger, it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu
ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A
+xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw
mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN
QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P
+0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I am now trying to declare the exact same string in Swift (Xcode 10.2) and have not been able to get it to work.

What I tried was this:

```
let pubKeyArray : [String]
let pubKey : String

self.pubKeyArray = ["-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu",
  "ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A",
  "+xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw",
  "mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN",
  "QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P",
  "+0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB",
  "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"]

self.pubKey = self.pubKeyArray.joined(separator: "\n")
```

When I display this string in the Debugger, it looks like this:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu\nERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A\n+xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw\nmwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN\nQSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P\n+0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

So basically, the new line character is not recognized. I also tried "\\n" and "\r\n", but to no avail.

What is the correct separator to use here?

Comment: Are you sure it's just not an issue of how the debugger is showing the string? What do you get if you do `print(self.pubKey)` ?

Comment: Unrelated, your code could be simplified using multiline strings using `"""`

Comment: Unrelated but your code could be greatly simplified by putting the certificate to a file and read it from that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than building an array and building a string from that, you can instead use a multi-line string literal. As [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID286) says:

> #### Multiline String Literals
>
> If you need a string that spans several lines, use a multiline string literal—a sequence of characters surrounded by three double quotation marks:
>
> ```
> let quotation = """
> The White Rabbit put on his spectacles.  "Where shall I begin,
> please your Majesty?" he asked.
>
> "Begin at the beginning," the King said gravely, "and go on
> till you come to the end; then stop."
> """
> ```

So, in your case:

```
let pubKey = """
    -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu
    ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A
    +xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw
    mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN
    QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P
    +0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB
    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

    """
```

Note that blank line between “END RSA PUBLIC KEY” line and the closing quotes. That’s because your original Objective-C example suggested that you wanted a newline at the end of that last line. If you don’t need that last newline character, just omit that blank line at the end, e.g.:

```
let pubKey = """
    -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBCgKCAQEA+xGZ/wcz9ugFpP07Nspo6U17l0YhFiFpxxU4pTk3Lifz9R3zsIsu
    ERwta7+fWIfxOo208ett/jhskiVodSEt3QBGh4XBipyWopKwZ93HHaDVZAALi/2A
    +xTBtWdEo7XGUujKDvC2/aZKukfjpOiUI8AhLAfjmlcD/UZ1QPh0mHsglRNCmpCw
    mwSXA9VNmhz+PiB+Dml4WWnKW/VHo2ujTXxq7+efMU4H2fny3Se3KYOsFPFGZ1TN
    QSYlFuShWrHPtiLmUdPoP6CV2mML1tk+l7DIIqXrQhLUKDACeM5roMx0kLhUWB8P
    +0uj1CNlNN4JRZlC7xFfqiMbFRU9Z4N6YwIDAQAB
    -----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
    """
```

Now, when you display this in the debugger, you’ll see the `\n` characters represented there, but that’s just an artifact of how the debugger represents non-visible characters. Rest assured that those are really newline characters.

Comment: The newline at the end of the last line was incorrect, edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The multiline string literal with """ worked fine - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The string you are seeing in the debugger is the `debugDescription` of the string. The `debugDescription` will replace things like the new line character with a backslash + `n` (It is supposed to make it clear that there is a new line).

If you want to see the actual string, you should just `print` it. In `lldb`, do:

```
po print(pubKey)
```